# Logger on multithread application causes exception because file is used by another procces c#

Tags: c#, logging, ioexception

i have a logger class for my application

```
    public class mylog
    {
        public static string nameoflogfile;
        public static void log(string text)
        {
            string tolog = "[" + String.Format("{0:d/M/yyyy HH:mm:ss:fff}", 
            DateTime.Now) + "] " + text;
            Console.WriteLine(tolog);
            File.AppendAllText("logs//" + nameoflogfile +".log", tolog);
        }
    }
```

I have multiple threads and sometimes more then one thread is trying to log at the same time and causing an IOexception.

is there a beter way to make my logger work than adding a try,catch and discard half of the events which i want to log?

thanks for any help

Comment: Add a `lock` around `File.AppendAllText`

Comment: Use a real logging library such as NLog or log4net.